# Which Pokémon cry out their name, and which don't?

Tags: pokemon-series

In Pokémon, certain Pokémon cries are the name of the creature while some are not.

Is there a list of Pokémon whose cries are their name and Pokémon whose cries aren't anywhere?

Comment: @Nolonar I disagree, some Pokémon very clearly say their name. The first that comes to mind is Chatot, whose cry is obviously "Perappu", but I've seen others. It's only a handful, mind you, but there are some.

Comment: @Nolonar If you can confidently say that Pikachu is the only case, then surely that's an answer rather than a close reason? And I don't see anywhere in the question where OP states it's regarding the anime specifically, so I'm not sure why you're voting to close under that pretense.

Comment: Point taken. I've retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 2):

Having watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAzNZd4wR1k) the whole way through, I'm fairly confident in saying that with the exception of [Pikachu](https://youtu.be/jAzNZd4wR1k?t=36s), all Pokémon have cries that are unintelligible noises.

This is the case for the games at least, the anime certainly has Pokémon other than Pikachu that say their own name. It could be argued that this is 'speaking' and not their 'cry' however.
In either case this question has also been duplicated on [Anime & Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/39226/which-pok%C3%A9mon-cry-out-their-name-and-which-dont), where that can be dealt with separately.